# using SMALL function to retrieve lowest value in range, trying to combine with OFFSET to get value to the left

Tags: excel-formula

I am using the SMALL formula in H2 to find the lowest price in the row, which works great.
`=IF(ISERROR(SMALL(A2:F2,COUNTIF(A2:F2,0)+1)),"",SMALL(A2:F2,COUNTIF(A2:F2,0)+1))`

I am having trouble retrieving the value to the left of it (its corresponding item#) with OFFSET.

```
  A   |  B    |   C   |  D    |   E   |   F   |          G         |          H
item# | price | item# | price | item# | price | lowest value item# | lowest value
123   |  70   | 456   | 80    | 789   | 67.89 |   ?                | 67.89
```

Also,I do not know which column will have the lowest value, A-F can change.
I've spent several hours searching and tried using the original formula as the Reference part for the OFFSET:
`=OFFSET(IF(ISERROR(SMALL(A2:F2,COUNTIF(A2:F2,0)+1)),"",SMALL(A2:F2,COUNTIF(A2:F2,0)+1)),0,-1,1,1)` and variations of it. This returns #Value!

Am I on the right track? Is OFFSET the correct way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would also remove the dependency on H2 by replacing it thus, simply adding a <kbd>MIN</kbd> function

```
=INDEX(A2:F2;MATCH(MIN(A2:F2);A2:F2;0)-1)
```

however, you always need to distinguish between item number and price. Sometimes the item value could be lower than price and then your formula wouldn't work. It would return the item value as the lowest value and then will return the price for the preceding item. It would be a mess. 
So to resolve this, you need to add two <kbd>MATCH</kbd> conditions to look for the exact match:
here is the formula the **LOWEST VALUE ITEM#**:

```
=INDEX(A2:F2;(MATCH(MIN(IF(A1:F1="Price";A2:F2));A2:F2;0)-1)*(MATCH("Item#";A1:F1;0)))
```

and the formula to find the **LOEWST VALUE PRICE**

```
=MIN(IF(A1:F1="Price";A2:F2))
```

For example in the following: 
[image]

Value in **C2** is the lowest, however it is not the lowest **price** value, which is itself in **F2** 
 That is why you need to add these **match** conditions to find the value above which is **item#** or above which is **Price**. 
So for **Price** I used **MIN(IF** and for **Item#** i used a **MATCH** condition.

here is [the excel sheet example downloadable from dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1l1h3q30b26hveu/min_if_match.xlsx?dl=0)

***P.S.*** 
**do NOT forget to adjust the formuals to your regional settings, by replacing the ";" with ","**

tell me if it works.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of MIN and MATCH. It works with or without empty cells in the array! I just needed to replace the semi-colons with commas and use ctrl-shift-enter to add the formulas.

Comment: @dinap if you tried this answer and it worked properly, you need to accept this as an answer to your question for future consultation by other users in Stackoverflow. Because the first answer returns unwanted behaviour as mentioned.

Comment: I changed this to the correct answer. I was testing both formulas with my original 3-digit item#s, while prices were still 2-digit, so missed the fact that your example works regardless of item number.

Answer (score 1):

*Is OFFSET the correct way to do this?* - No

`OFFSET` expects as its first parameter a range reference, not a value.

If your prices are unique, use this (if they are not, I'm not sure what result you would expect)

```
=INDEX(A2:F2,MATCH(H2,A2:F2,0)-1)
```

That said, your `SMALL` formula looks suspect.  It looks like you want to return `""` if all the prices are `0`.  But your formula will return the smallest `item#` in that case.  Can you confirm or explain?

Comment: Some of the rows will have more items than others, so there will be blank cells. It seems to be working fine with the ""; tried removing it, but it then returns #NA and FALSE for G and H respectively. Your INDEX worked perfectly. Thank you for the example.

Comment: This formula returns the lowest value in the range **A2:F2** regardless of whether it is item or price value.<br> So if there is an item value which is the lowest of all, then the formula will return the **PRICE** value to the left of this *item* value which is totally wrong.<br>Therefore, one **MATCH** condition and one **MIN(IF())** are needed to get the exact matches. This is explained extensively in **[my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27100385/4230650)**.